# multitasking example from a site

Tags: assembly, x86

This is the material that I have been looking at
http://hosted.cjmovie.net/TutMultitask.htm

appreciate if anyone can help me out with the following assembly coding

```
pusha          ;Push all standard registers
push ds        ;Push segment d
push es        ;Push segmetn e
push fs        ; ''
push gs        ; ''
```

The registers and segments are saved in the kernel-level stack of the process, is that correct?

```
mov eax, 0x10  ;Get kernel data segment
mov ds, eax    ;Put it in the data segment registers
mov es, eax
mov fs, eax
mov gs, eax
```

what is the purpose of loadinhg the kernel data segment descriptor?

```
push esp       ;Push pointer to all the stuff we just pushed
call _TaskSwitch ;Call C code
```

why is the esp saved before calling _TaskSwitch?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code says it clearly in the comments: "Push pointer to all the stuff we just pushed" + "Call C code", see also `TaskSwitch()`:

```
//Switch between our two tasks
//Notice how we get the old esp from the ASM code
//It's not a pointer, but we actually get the ESP value
//That way we can save it in our task structure
unsigned int TaskSwitch(unsigned int OldEsp)
```

So, `TaskSwitch()` receives (as a parameter) the address of or a pointer to the context saved by the ISR on the stack. `TaskSwitch()` also returns a pointer/address of some context saved on the stack. If it returns the same value as it received, no switch occurs, it's a simple call+return. If it returns a different one, a switch occurs, because the return is done using a different context and to a different address.

Read the document you're referring to and the code described in it. It's all very clearly written there.